# Bitronix connection reset issue

Tags: oracle11g, jta, spring-transactions, bitronix

I seem to get this error when deployed code to our linux environment, not sure what does this mean

Please can someone help me to explain and possible fix?

java.sql.SQLException: unable to get a connection from pool of a PoolingDataSource containing an XAPool of resource actdb with 1 connection(s).....
(0 still available)
at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:262) ~[btm-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IO Error: Connection reset
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:428) ~[ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:536) ~[ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:228) ~[ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) ~[ojdbc5-11.2.0.2.jar:11.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your maximum transaction count. It seems your setup has only one connection for your datasource and 0 is available. This means you have no idle connections.

https://github.com/bitronix/btm/wiki/JDBC-pools-configuration

```
myDataSource.setMinPoolSize(0);                                                                 
myDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(5);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, yes this is my configuration, and issue still exists, only on Linux environment.

Comment: Since original link is long gone, have an archived copy:
https://web.archive.org/web/20150520175210/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/JdbcConfiguration2x